# How to create folder structure in Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I am deploying Azure Functions using ARMTemplate and adding all function files from powershell.

**PowerShell Code:**

```
 $FileContent = "$(Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Raw)"                   

 $FilesArr[$FileName] =$FileContent                

    $props = @{
                config = @{
                    bindings = ""
                }
                files = $FilesArr
                test_data = ""
            }
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/functions -ResourceName $SiteName/$FunctionName -PropertyObject $props -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

I want create folder structure in deployed function app.
for e.g.: SampleAzureFunction is my Function Name and files included in this function are:

- Shared\Model.csx
- function.json
- project.json
- run.csx

  [image]

I want to create **Shared** folder and add Model.csx file to the folder in Azure function

wwwroot/Function folder structure in Kudu:

[image]

How to create this structure?

Comment: Have you tried just using `Shared\Model.csx` as the FileName? I *think* that will work.

Comment: yes..I tried using Shared\Model.csx, deployment succeeds but Shared folder is not created. And the file is copied in wwwroot/function folder after deployment. I have modified the question with wwwroot folder snapshot..

Comment: @Amruta I test in my lab, I get the same result with you, I could not create a directory. Maybe you could create a zip contains all of your directory and folders and use Kudu APi to upload it to function app.

Comment: @Amruta You could check step 7. https://clouddeveloper.space/2017/10/26/deploy-azure-function-using-powershell/

Comment: Looks like there is indeed a bug preventing `Shared/Model.csx` from working. However, you should be getting a failure when trying this, and it should not simply ignore the folder. Please try running with `-Debug` and look at the request to make sure the slash is not getting lost somewhere when PowerShell sends the ARM request. But as @ShengbaoShui-MSFT suggests, there are alternate means of deploying all the files at once without having to include them in the ARM request.